# MySQL Install - Unable to update security settings. Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: mysql, windows, service, virus

I'm using administrator account in windows7.

Recently I got some error in using this OS because of the virus (may be) which stops all "service".

I could not find the virus which antivirus, but I solved the problem by changing the settings of service in "msconfig".

After some day, I tried to install mysql server in my computer for some reasons.

But I got some error like below

```
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:56 - Attempting to update security settings.
mysql-server-5.6-winx64:100 - Unable to update security settings. Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

I seems to be the aftereffect of virus or my misunderstanding in install steps.
Would you guess some idea?

Comment: Looks like installing MySQL installation is not related with the changes of your "msconfig". Updating security settings is second step. First of all check whether MySQL service has been started or not! Let me know your result

Comment: When i start MySQL servcie in "NET START MYSQL56" or in "service", it stops after about 3 seconds... does it answer? @ursitesion

Comment: Is MySQL listed in your service list?

Comment: Yeah. I also inserted currrent user(administrator) in the list of "Log on as ervcie" option!

Comment: Before security settings, create another user and GRANT all permissions to that.

Comment: > When i start MySQL servcie in "NET START MYSQL56" or in "service", it stops after about 3 seconds... does it answer?
I means that I said MYSQL56 is started .. but .. After about 3 secs when I look at service list, MYSQL56 was stooped

Comment: Then, check your logs in Windows event viewer first.

Comment: Ok actually now im away from my computer i will check that 2 hrs later

Comment: @ursitesion In Windows Log -> Application Section,

 
error starts with event data like following
    TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).  
(level of alert)

Following log is with some information and errors with eventdata
    TCP/IP, --shared-memory, or --named-pipe should be configured on NT OS 
    Aborting

Windows Log -> System Section, 
- EventData 

  param1 MySQL56 
  param2 5 


- EventData 

  param1 MySQL56 
  param2 run
   4D007900530051004C00350036002F0034000000

Answer (score -2):

When asked for the Current root password, leave that field blank. Then the server installed ok.